# Accessing a vector inside a vector

Tags: r, vector, indexing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to access an index within a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221746/is-there-a-way-to-access-an-index-within-a-vector)

I've posted a similar question recently, however i didn't really receive an answer. 
I need to access a vector within a list of vectors, this is what the code looks like so far:

```
MyDataR1 <- scan("D:\\R Code\\Residential\\bvl5 res.txt",what='character') 
MyDataR2 <- scan("D:\\R Code\\Residential\\bvl5 res.txt",what='character') 
MyDataR3 <- scan("D:\\R Code\\Residential\\cpk11 res.txt",what='character')

MyDataR <- c(MyDataR1,MyDataR2,MyDataR3)
print (MyDataR[3])
```

However the print command doesn't actually print the 3rd vector (MyDataR3), it prints out the 3rd value from the 1st vector (MyDataR1)

Is there any way to access the individual vectors within a vector?? And how would i go about accessing the individual value of a vector within a vector? I thought it would look like this:

```
MyDataR[[3]][5] <- 5    #this would access the 5th value of the 3rd vector and modifies it
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does `str(MyDaraR1)` and `str(MyDaraR)` show us? I suspect the `c()` operation just stuck the three vectors into a single vector hence then observed behaviour. If you put each of the vector into a list then what you show should work; `MyDataR[[3]]` would return the 3rd component of the list, and the replacement code you show would also work. Form your list via `MyDataR <- list(MyDataR1,MyDataR2,MyDataR3)`

Comment: This is essentially the same question you asked a week ago: [Is there a way to access an index within a vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221746/is-there-a-way-to-access-an-index-within-a-vector).  And you're still confusing vectors with lists even though @Andrie showed you the difference in his answer to your previous question.

Comment: @Ice Phoenix: Don't read this comment; it will further confuse.  @Joshua Ulrich: Try `is.vector(list())`.

Comment: @Richie Cotton: yes, lists are technically vectors but most R users I've encountered refer to the atomic types as "vectors" and "list-vectors" as "lists".  It's confusing.  How would you explain it more clearly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that this line:

```
MyDataR <- c(MyDataR1,MyDataR2,MyDataR3)
```

does not do what you think it is doing. It is combining the three arguments into a single vector. Here's a reproducible example of what's going on:

```
foo <- 1:3
bar <- 4:6
baz <- 7:9

foobarbaz <- c(foo, bar, baz)
> foobarbaz
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

What you want to do is create a list object:

```
mylist <- list(foo, bar, baz)
> mylist[3]
[[1]]
[1] 7 8 9
```

And can be indexed as you thought:

```
mylist[[3]][2] <- -1
> mylist[3]
[[1]]
[1]  7 -1  9
```

Answer (score -1):

`c` is short for concatenation, so this behavior is obvious. Try using `list` instead.